# Is there a way to use surv.aorsf with Harrel's concordance in MLR3?

Tags: mlr3

I am trying to use the surv.aorsf implementation in mlr3extralearners with the ’cstat’ split_rule setting. This parameter is valid in the orsf package. on the surv.aorsf mlr3 page (see [here](https://mlr3extralearners.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_learners_surv.aorsf.html)) the parameter is not listed, but in the example code at the bottom it is included.

When I run that code:

```
learner = mlr3::lrn("surv.aorsf")
learner$param_set$ids()
```

the parameter is not included, and when I try to initialise a learner with the parameter specified, i.e. with

```
ao_tuning_L = lrn("surv.aorsf",split_rule="cstat",
                   split_min_events = to_tune(2,10),
                   mtry = to_tune(1,9),
                   n_retry = to_tune(0, 5),
                   n_tree = to_tune(100, 1000))
```

I get the following error:
"Error in x$public_methods : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"
This works for other models, such as surv.cforest and the "teststat" parameter.

I wonder if the parameter was omitted for a reason or overlooked? In order to do this I think I will need to build a custom learner, but I am not sure where to start. Is there a way to import all of the settings for surv.aorsf except for the split_rule?

--------- EDIT:

with updated mlr3extralearners and mlr3tuning, when running the next bit of code:

```
tuner_resampling =2
runs=2
rats<-survival::rats
rats$sex<-(rats$sex=="f")*1
tsk_rats = as_task_surv(rats, time = "time",
                        event = "status", type = "right", id = "rats")

ao_tuning_L = lrn("surv.aorsf",split_rule="cstat")
ao_tuner_L = tnr("random_search")
set_threads(ao_tuning_L, n = threads)
ao_instance_L = ti(tsk_rats,
                   learner=ao_tuning_L,
                   resampling = rsmp("cv",folds=tuner_resampling),
                   measure = msr("surv.cindex"),
                   terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = runs, k = 0))
ao_hyper_L <- ao_tuner_L$optimize(ao_instance_L)
```

I get the following error:
"Error: there were unrecognized arguments:
split_rule is unrecognized - did you mean n_split?"

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `split_rule` was added 3 days ago.
You therefore need to update your version of `mlr3extralearners` by for example running:

```r
remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3extralearners")
```

PS: Updating a package to the latest dev version is almost always a good idea to troubleshoot issues.